# Pandas - Remove Columns based on values in another dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas called as `df_A` which in real-time has more than 100 columns.

And, I have another dataframe `df_B` in which two columns gives me what columns do I need from the `df_A`

A reproducible example has been given below,

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'foo':[100, 111, 222], 
     'bar':[333, 444, 555],'foo2':[110, 101, 222], 
     'bar2':[333, 444, 555],'foo3':[100, 111, 222], 
     'bar3':[333, 444, 555]}

df_A = pd.DataFrame(d)

d = {'ReqCol_A':['foo','foo2'], 
     'bar':[333, 444],'foo2':[100, 111], 
     'bar2':[333, 444],'ReqCol_B':['bar3', ''], 
     'bar3':[333, 444]}

df_b = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

As it can be seen `df_b` in the above example, the values under `ReqCol_A` and `ReqCol_B` is what I am trying to get from `df_A`

so, my expected output will have three columns from `df_A`. The three columns will foo foo2 and bar3.

`df_C` will be the expected output and it will look like

```
df_C
foo foo2 bar3
100 110  333
111 101  444
222 222  555
```

Please help me with this. I am struggling to get this.

Comment: I'm a little lost on what you are after. Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: @busybear added to the question now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
# retrieve all the unique elements from your df_b columns (ReqCol_A and ReqCol_B) let it also include nan and other unwanted features
features = set(df_b.ReqCol_A.unique()) | set(df_b.ReqCol_B.unique())

# Taking intersection with df_A column names and fetching the names which need to be targeted
target_features = set(df_A.columns) & features

# Get the Output
df_A.loc[:,target_features]
```

---

**Performance comparison**

Given method:

```
%%timeit
features = set(df_b.ReqCol_A.unique()) | set(df_b.ReqCol_B.unique())
target_features = set(df_A.columns) & features
df_A.loc[:,target_features]
875 µs ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Second answer (using filter):

```
%%timeit 
df_A[df_b.filter(like='ReqCol').replace('', np.nan).stack().tolist()]
2.14 ms ± 51.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Clearly, the given method is much faster than other.

Comment: What if you had more that 10 'ReqCol_x' type them out manually or use filter?

Comment: @ScottBoston In that case, I do follow `filter` however with given constraint I don't think there's a need of filter.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `filter` to get only those columns with 'ReqCol' then `stack` to get a list and filter the db_A dataframe:

```
df_A[df_b.filter(like='ReqCol').replace('', np.nan).stack().tolist()]
```

Output:

```
   foo  bar3  foo2
0  100   333   100
1  111   444   111
2  222   555   222
```